# Find the maximum of $x^3_{1}+x^3_{2}+x^3_{3}-x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$ subject to $0 \le x_i \le i, \forall i$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization

> Let $$0\le x_{i}\le i,\, i=1,2,3$$ be real numbers. Find the maximum of the expression
> $$x^3_{1}+x^3_{2}+x^3_{3}-x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}$$

---

**My idea:** I guess
$$x^3_{1}+x^3_{2}+x^3_{3}-x_{1}x_{2}x_{3}\le 0^3+2^3+3^3-0\cdot2\cdot 3=35$$

But I can't prove it. Can you help ?

This problem is a special case of:
[image]

Comment: I guess? Why is that step even remote true? The maximum is certainly at least that value, but that's not an argument.

Comment: I don't think this is a "good" special case for the 25-variables problem. In the 25-variables problem, there are 25-cross terms $x_1x_2x_3,\ldots, x_{24}x_{25}x_1, x_{25}x_1x_2$. The special case you want to look at is probably the one for $x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 - 3x_1x_2x_3$.

Comment: yes,If I post the four variables problem,that's a special case

Comment: I think your 3-D situation, is not suitable for your question, you know the variable $S$ denotes $\sum\limits_{cyc}x_{i}^3-\sum\limits_{cyc}x_{i}x_{i+1}x_{i+2}$, so because of the well known equality $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\left(\frac{(a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+a)^2}{2}\right)$, threee times $S$ gives $3S=\frac12\sum\limits_{cyc}(x_{i}+x_{i+1}+x_{i+2})((x_{i}-x_{i+1})^2+(x_{i+1}-x_{i+2})^2+(x_{i+2}-x_{i})^2)$, so if you want do resolve that special case, I think this would help.

Comment: If I didn't make any mistake, the maximum for the $25$-variable problem is achieved at $$(x_1,\ldots,x_{25}) = 
( 0, 0, 3, 4,  0, 6, 7, 0, 9, 10, 0,12,13, 0,15,16, 0,18,19, 0,21,22, 0,24,25)$$
with value $75824$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

As the objective function is convex and continuous, and the domain of interest is compact and convex, so we must have maximum when each $x_i \in \{0, i\}$.  This cuts down the problem (even the general $n$ variable case) to checking a few extreme cases, many of which are trivial...

Comment: Hello,use this methods can solve this problem?http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/869709/how-find-this-maximum-sum-i-1nx3-i-x-ix-i1x-i2-x-n1-x

Comment: +1 @chinamath, yes you can. this is how I can restrict my search and get the answer for the $25$-variable I claimed in my comment.

Comment: @achillehui,How find it? and How prove this 75824 is maximum?

Comment: @chinamath there are only $2^{25}$ cases to check. It is perfectly doable by a computer.

Comment: @achillehui,哈哈，这个题是一张联赛模拟试题最后一个加试试题上的,achlille老师.我估计他后面答案是利用调整法.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just differentiate the expression and set the derivatives to 0?

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = 0\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3} = 0
$$

and solve for the three variables

Comment: Hello,I don't linke this mathods.becasue this equation is not easy to slove,and follow is very ugly

Comment: Why don't you like the method? Derivatives is the common way to find min/max

Comment: This only works on the interior.

Comment: because this problem is three  variables,In fact, After a while I can post $25$variable

Comment: It finds relative extrema.

Comment: It finds relative extrema on the interior of the cube only.

Comment: But $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k} = 0$ is the condition for both a maximum and a minimim. your statement is incomplete...

Answer (score 3):

The general question: Given is

$$
f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) = \sum_k x_k^n - \prod_k x_k,
$$

and let

$$
\forall 1 \le k \le n : 0 \le x_k \le k.
$$

Find the maximum of $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)$.

---

First we define

$$
x_k = k \sin^2(\phi_k),
$$

whence the condition

$$
\forall 1 \le k \le n : 0 \le x_k \le k.
$$

is satisfied.

---

For a maximum, we have the condition

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_p} = 0 \wedge
  \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} < 0.
$$

---

We now have

$$
f(\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_n) = \sum_k k^n \sin^{2n}(\phi_k) - n! \prod_k \sin^2(\phi_k),
$$

whence

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_p} =
  \sin(2 \phi_p) \left( n p^n \sin^{2n-2}(\phi_p)  - n! \prod_{k \ne p} \sin^2(\phi_k) \right),
$$

and

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} &=&
  n(2n-2) p^n \sin^2(2 \phi_p) \sin^{2n-4}(\phi_p) \\
&& + 2\cos(2 \phi_p) \left( n p^n \sin^{2n-2}(\phi_p)  - n! \prod_{k \ne p} \sin^2(\phi_k) \right),
\end{eqnarray}
$$

---

The extreme value of $f(\phi_1\cdots,\phi_n)$ is given by the condition

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi_p} = 0 \Rightarrow
  \sin(2 \phi_p) \left( n p^n \sin^{2n-2}(\phi_p)  - n! \prod_{k \ne p} \sin^2(\phi_k) \right) = 0\\
\Downarrow\\
\sin(2\phi_p) = 0 \vee \sin(\phi_p) = 0 \vee p \sin^2(\phi_p) =q \sin^2(\phi_q).
$$

We have:

- The condition $p \sin^2(\phi_p) =q \sin^2(\phi_q)$,
  implies that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} > 0$,
  i.e. a *minimum*.
- The condition $\sin(\phi_p) = 0$,
  implies that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} = 0$.
- The condition $\sin(2\phi_p) = 0$,
  implies that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} = n! - np^n$,
  thus $\displaystyle \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial \phi_p^2} < 0$,
  if $p>1$, i.e. een *maximum* for $p>1$.

The maximum is therefore given for

$$
\phi_1 = 0 \wedge p>1 : \phi_p = \pi/2,
$$

and the maximum is given by

$$
\boxed{
f_\textrm{max} = \sum_{p>1} p^n.
}
$$

---

A small modification due to some minor errors, thanks to [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews)!

Comment: Using sin is a neat way of avoiding the problems of the boundaries of the domain, but isn't $\sin \pi = 0$? You seem to be interchanging $p$ and $k$ in that last formula...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: You are correct, a small error... I will edit it...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: The condition is $\sin(2\phi_p) = 0$, thus $\phi_p = \pi/2$...

Answer (score 2):

Step 1:  rescale the variables (to see why this is valid, see the addition, below), replacing $y_1=x_1, y_2=x_2/2, y_3=x_3/3$ so that they are on $0\le y_i\le 1$.

on the interior we have

$$\nabla f= \langle 3y_1^2-y_2y_3, 3y_2^2-y_1y_3, 3y_3^2-y_1y_2\rangle=\langle 0,0,0\rangle$$

So

> $$\begin{cases}3y_1^2=y_2y_3\quad (1) \\ 3y_2^2=y_1y_3\quad (2) \\ 3y_3^2=y_1y_2\quad (3)\end{cases}$$

Since the interior has $y_1y_2y_3\ne 0$ we can divide $(1)$ by $(2)$ to get ${y_1^2\over y_2^2}={y_2\over y_1}$ i.e. $y_1^3=y_2^3\iff y_1=y_2$ and by symmetry $y_1=y_2=y_3$, which means $2y_i^2=0$ impossible, hence no critical points on the interior.

The whole shape is a cube, so we have to check $6$ sides. On any of the planes where a $y_i=0$ we get a reduction to $y_j^3+y_k^3$ with $0\le y_i,y_j\le 1$ which you can solve by inspection to have the max value $2$.

The other possibilities are some $y_i=1$ on the boundary giving $y_j^3+y_k^3-y_jy_k+1$ with $0\le y_j, y_k\le 1$.

Optimizing this we need to solve

$$\langle 3y_j^2-y_k, 3y_k^2-y_j\rangle =\langle 0,0\rangle.$$

So

> $$\begin{cases}3y_j^2=y_k \quad (1)'\\ 3y_k^2=y_j\quad (2)'\end{cases}$$

Again, dividing $(1)'$ by $(2)'$ we conclude $y_j=y_k=0$ which is not on the interior, so we discard it.

This just leaves the edge lines where $y_i=y_j=1$ and $0\le y_k\le 1$, this is a $1$-variable optimization problem:

We have $2+y_k^3-y_k$ i to be optimized, so that we check $3y_k^2-1=0\iff y_k=\sqrt{1\over 3}$, and the endpoint where $y_k=1$.

From here revert to $x$ coordinates and try the options out to get the max.

---

This method generalizes to any number of variables by induction, seeing the interior constraints will always reduce to all variables being $0$, so you can do the same sort of test after going back to normal coordinates. And if you do the computation even for just $2$ variables, you'll see how to compute without having to check them all.

---

**Addition**

For those wondering why it's sufficient to just consider the $y$ critical points instead of directly the $x$ ones, here is the justification:

Let

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 3\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $f(y)=f(A^{-1}x)$ and $f(x)=f(Ay)$.

The critical points are where the derivative, $Df=0$ (in $x$ coordinates), that is to say:

$D_x(f(x)) = f'(Ay)$ by the chain rule since linear maps are their own derivatives. But since $A$ is invertible, $D_y(f(x))=f'(Ay)A=f'(x)A$. This is $0$ iff $f'(x)$ is, ergo we can test for critical points in either coordinate system.

It's the same idea why diffeomorphisms are Tangent bundle isomorphisms, you're doing the same process here with a simple, invertible linear map.

Comment: No time to check this, but it is the right approach to investigate the relative extrema and the values on the boundary.

Comment: You $\nabla f$ is off, you forget to put back the scaling factor for each term when you substitute $x_i$ by $\color{red}{i} y_i$.

Comment: I don't think I need to: linear changes of variables will give the same corresponding critical points since the matrix is nonsingular (chain rule).

Comment: @AdamHughes Did you, for example, consider, that $0 \leq X_{25} \leq 25$ ?

Comment: @calculus I don't understand your question.

Comment: In the exercise it is given, that $0 \leq X_i \leq i \ \text{for} \ i=1,2,3,...,25$. Did you consider that ?

Comment: @achillehui I've made an addition to explain why it is sufficient to compute the critical points in the $y$ coordinates, in case you're interested.

Comment: @calculus The problem is in $3$ variables if you read it; the excerpt in the post is to show what the op's question is a special case of. However, if you go through the process I describe, you can see that induction will give you the answer in more variables with the same methodology.

Comment: @AdamHughes Now I see. With the transformation of the variable, $0\leq x_i \leq i \ \text{for} \ i=1,2,3$ is equal to $0 \leq y_i \leq 1 \ \text{for} \ i=1,2,3$. I´m correct ?

Comment: @AdamHughes I've no problem you evaluate the critical points in $y$ coordinates. I'm saying the $\nabla f$ you computed is off, should be $(3 y_1^2 - 6y_2y_3, 24 y_2^2 - 6y_1y_3, 81 y_3^2 - 6y_1y_2)$. This is not equivalent to what you are analyzing.

Comment: @achillehui It is for the sake of finding where the simultaneous zeros are, that's what the chain rule is giving us. It's just like in the one variable case where you look at $g(ax)$ instead of $g(x)$. The function is the same thing, it's just considered in different variables, ${d\over dx}g(ax)=g'(ax)\cdot a$ and with $y=ax$ we have ${d\over dy}g(ax)=g'(ax)$. Since $a$ is nonzero, the "same" critical points will emerge, i.e. if the first one has a singular derivative at $x=1$ the second will at $x=a$. If you check you'll see the same conclusion at the same points. (contd.)

Comment: @achillehui (contd.) Your expression uses the derivative with respect to $x$, mine uses the one with respect to $y$, they don't give the same numbers, but the same points emerge because the linear transformation is invertible. If you plug in with your version, you'll see the same conclusion comes out, I still have $2y_i^2=0$ as the conclusion after doing the division to get $y_1=2y_2=3y_3$, just with more work. That's the power of this kind of change of variables, it avoids the work for the same payoff, so that the method generalizes to $n$ variables easily.

Comment: @calculus yes, that's correct.

Comment: Correction to my first response in the two-parter to @achillehui the second one should read "[...]the second will at $y=a$[...]"

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{You can use Mathematica to verify your results.}$

```
Clear["Global`*"];
OptimizeFunc@n_ := 
  Module[{}, 
   obj = Sum[x[i]^3, {i, n}] - 
     Sum[x[i]*x[Mod[i + 1, n, 1]]*x[Mod[i + 2, n, 1]], {i, n}];
   Print[obj];
   constraints = Flatten[Table[{0 <= x[i] <= i}, {i, n}]];
   variables = Table[x[i], {i, n}];
   NMaximize[{obj, constraints}, variables]];
OptimizeFunc[3]
OptimizeFunc[25]
```

$\color{red}{\text{The below results calculated by Mathematica may be wrong.}}$

```
{35., {x[1] -> -3.84172*10^-17, x[2] -> 2., x[3] -> 3.}}


{67743., {x[1] -> 1., x[2] -> 0., x[3] -> 3., x[4] -> 4., x[5] -> 0., 
  x[6] -> 6., x[7] -> 7., x[8] -> 0., x[9] -> 9., x[10] -> 0., 
  x[11] -> 11., x[12] -> 12., x[13] -> 0., x[14] -> 14., x[15] -> 15.,
   x[16] -> 0., x[17] -> 17., x[18] -> 18., x[19] -> 0., x[20] -> 20.,
   x[21] -> 0., x[22] -> 22., x[23] -> 23., x[24] -> 0., 
  x[25] -> 25.}}
```

---

## Note

The **multitude of maximization functions** in Mathematica is due to the different types of problems they are designed to handle, and the different methods they employ. Here's a brief overview:

- `Maximize` tries to find an exact global maximum if the problem is suitably simple. For more complex problems, it may only find a local maximum or may not be able to find a maximum at all.
- `NMaximize` finds a numerical approximation to the global maximum. It is $\color{red}{\text{more likely to find the global maximum}}$ for complex problems than `Maximize`, but the result is an approximation.
- `FindMaximum` finds a local maximum for more complex expressions. It may not find the global maximum, especially for functions with many local maxima.
- `NArgMax` finds a numerical approximation of the arguments of the maximum, but doesn't return the maximum value itself.
- `ArgMax`: Like `Maximize`, but only returns the arguments at which the maximum is attained, not the maximum value itself.
- `MaxValue`: This function gives the maximum value of a function over the region, but does not return the arguments at which the maximum value is achieved.
- `FindMaxValue`: Like `FindMaximum`, but only returns the maximum value, not the position of the maximum.
- `ConstrainedMax`: This is used for constrained linear optimization. It provides the maximum value of a linear function subject to linear constraints.
- others

  - `MaxDetect`: This is a function in image processing that detects local maxima in an image.
  - `MaximalBy`: This function can be used with lists and gives the elements for which a certain function is maximized.

Answer (score 0):

*Remark*: Here is a solution without using calculus.

Let $f := x_1^3 + x_2^3 + x_3^3 - x_1 x_2 x_3$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 f &\le x_1 + 2^2x_2 + 3^2x_3 - x_1x_2x_3 \\
 &= x_1 + 4x_2 + (9 - x_1x_2)x_3 \\
 &\le x_1 + 4x_2 + (9 - x_1x_2)\cdot 3\\
 &= 27 + x_1 + (4 - 3x_1)x_2 \\
 &\le 27 + x_1 + (4 - 3x_1)\cdot 2\\
 &= 35 - 5x_1 \\
 &\le 35.
\end{align*}

Also, when $x_1 = 0, x_2 = 2, x_3 = 3$,
we have $f = 35$.

Thus, the maximum of $f$ is $35$.